# SQL Query String Manipulation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql

This question relates to string manipulation in javascript. Might sound redundant but I am currently facing huge difficulty in solving this.

I have two strings(basically WHERE Clause of SQL)

```
var QueryOne = (Name != '') AND (date_entered BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59') AND (salutation != '');
var QueryTwo = (Name LIKE('%link%')) AND (salutation = '')
```

I want to scan QueryOne with QueryTwo and want QueryOne to become

```
(Name LIKE('%link%'))  AND (date_entered BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59') AND  (salutation = '')
```

I have looked into some plugins but they are all difference checker. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Nope, really not following what the question is here? `var QueryOne = (Name != '') AND (date_entered BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59') AND (salutation != '');` isn't valid syntax?

Comment: This is a parsing problem not a string manipulation problem. The two `salutation =` tests are contradictory, which wins & why?  Why is the condition order changed?.  Parsing SQL like this makes me nervous.

Comment: I want to scan QueryOne for changes as shown in QueryTwo. QueryTwo is basically runtime filter that user can change. I want to scan QueryOne for changes. If QueryOne is not like QueryTwo, I want to incorporate those changes. I have given what Final Query should look like.

Comment: Search the queries for all the entities like `Name`, `date_entered`. `SPLIT` both the queries on  `AND`, `OR` and whatever else you expect.  Replace the entities which match and add which don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to Add Identifier for the parts of string that I wanted to Change on run-time. It was directly related to my other post on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125023/elements-getting-replaced-at-wrong-indexes)