# Elements getting replaced at wrong indexes

Tags: javascript, string

I have a whereClause in which "double aesteric" indicates the position where the string is to be replaced with a part of secondClause as shown in the code. I want the whereClause to become '(cop != "kong") AND (king = "king") AND (king = "long")'.

I took some help from this forum and stumbled on the locations function. However after running my code I am getting this as final string

> ((cop != "kong")*) AND (**kon = "link"(king = "king")

How do I get it right? can't figure out whats wrong here.

```js
var whereClause = '(**kon = "link"**) AND (**kon = "link"**) AND (king = "long")';
var secondClause = '(cop != "kong") AND (king = "king")';
secondClause = secondClause.split('AND');
var arr = locations('**', whereClause); //[1, 15, 24, 38]

var whereClause_broken = whereClause.split('');
var secondIndex = 0;
for (let index = 0; index <= (arr.length / 2); index += 2) {
  var removed = whereClause_broken.splice(arr[index], arr[index + 1], secondClause[secondIndex]); // arr is modified
  secondIndex++;
}

whereClause_broken = whereClause_broken.join('');

function locations(substring, string) {
  var a = [],
    i = -1;
  while ((i = string.indexOf(substring, i + 1)) >= 0) a.push(i);
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when I called locations function it gave me the locations based upon the state of string before manipulation. And inside for loop the string was getting manipulated, so the original locations were not valid anymore. Had to call locations function at each iteration of the loop to get the latest location. That fixed my problem.

```js
var whereClause = '(**kon = "link"**) AND (**kon = "link"**) AND (king = "long")';
var secondClause = '(cop != "kong") AND (king = "king")';
secondClause = secondClause.split(') AND (');
 var counter = locations('**',whereClause);
 var secondIndex = 0;

var new_whereClause = whereClause;
var secondIndex = 0;
for (let index = 0; index <= (arr.length / 2); index += 2) {
  var arr = locations('**',new_whereClause);
 //console.log('arr :',arr,secondClause);
var chucnkStr = new_whereClause.substring(arr[0],arr[1]+2); // adding 2 because substring returns location of second instance one less than actual.
new_whereClause = new_whereClause.replace(chucnkStr,secondClause[secondIndex].replace(/[()]/g, ''));
 secondIndex ++;
}
```